# Hosting a Lightswitch app on a SharePoint 2010

Tags: silverlight, hosting

Is there a way/workaround to host a Lightswitch v 1.0 app on a SharePoint 2010 site ? 
This question was also posted on MSDN forum here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitchgeneral/thread/fb1252ec-ff77-4550-b052-7a11904e9647/

But there is not solution for now.